# Prove $\{n \in \mathbb N \mid 5 \text{ mod } 19 = 2\} = \varnothing$

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

> Prove
>   $$\{n \in \mathbb N \mid 5 \text{ mod } 19 = 2\} = \varnothing.
> $$

I know it's false but IDK how to prove it?

Comment: what do you mean it is false? It looks true

Comment: The definition of the set is *correct*, and the statement is *true*. But the definition of the set is *strange*, for beyond the sign "$|$" the $n$ does not appear. It is something like "I will buy every car such that the moon is a cube". Are there no typos?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895661/prove-n-%E2%88%88-natural-5n-mod-19-2-%E2%88%85 coincidence?

Answer (score 4):

$\{ n\in \Bbb N\mid 5\bmod 19=2\}$ is the set of natural numbers where the condition, $5\bmod 19=2$, holds true.

The condition is false, and a constant ( $n$ is not a term of the condition † ).

There are no natural numbers which make the condition true.

The set is empty.

$\blacksquare$

---

† Why is the bound variable, $n$, not a term of the condition?   It is a strange construction, but not technically invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Because
$$5 \, \text{mod}\, 19 \ne 2$$
So
$$\left\{n \in \mathbb{N} | 5 \, 
\text{mod} \, 19 =2\right\}=\emptyset$$

Answer (score 2):

The statement
$$
5 \text{ mod } 9 = 2
$$
is poor shorthand for
$$
5 \equiv 2 \pmod{9}
$$
which is a **false statement**, as you have noticed.

Then, what is
$$
\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \; \mid \; 5 \equiv 2 \pmod{9}\}?
$$

Well, it is the collection of natural numbers such that $5 \equiv 2 \pmod{9}$.
If there were any element of it, then it would follow that $5 \equiv 2 \pmod{9}$ *for that element*; but this can't be true. Hence
$$
\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid 5 \equiv 2 \pmod{9}\} = \varnothing.
$$
This latter statement (the entire thing) is a **true statement**.

---

#### A note about types

Normally when we use set-builder notation, we write
$$\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \phi(n)\}$$
where $\phi(n)$ is some *statement about $n$*. A "statement about $n$" is a function, $\phi: \mathbb{N} \to \{\top,\bot\}$. On input $n$, $\phi$ returns true or false.

But in this case, the statement, rather than being a function of $n$, contains no reference to $n$ at all.
The set construction $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid 5 \equiv 2 \pmod{19}\}$
seems to instead be an instance of
$$
\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \phi\}
$$
where $\phi$ is just a boolean, $\phi \in \{\top, \bot\}$.

Therefore, this reads like a *type mismatch*: we expect a function of $n$, and instead we get a constant, true-or-false statement. In this way, the question is deliberately confusing!

The resolution is that, given any boolean $\phi: \{\top, \bot\}$, we may interpret it as a *constant function*, which ignores its one natural number argument and just returns $\phi$.
Doing so, we resolve the apparent type confusion.

This is an instance of **subtyping:** $\{\top, \bot\}$ is understood as a subtype of $\mathbb{N} \to \{\top, \bot\}$.